# How to map a enum into an array with elements with the values of the items of the enum itself in TypeScript?

Tags: arrays, typescript

E.g. with a TS enum as below.

```
export enum UserType {
    Guest = 1,
    SNS = 2,
    Account = 3,
    Certified = 4,
}
```

Can I do Object.map(or other ways) to make an array with the following values without hard-coding?

```
        const atrributeOptions = [
            {
                type: UserType.Guest,
                isSelect: filterCondition.filter((item) => item.type === UserType.Guest)[0].isSelect,
                onClick: this.onToggleFilterItem.bind(this, UserType.Guest),
            },
            {
                type: UserType.Certified,
                isSelect: filterCondition.filter((item) => item.type === UserType.Certified)[0].isSelect,
                onClick: this.onToggleFilterItem.bind(this, UserType.Certified),
            },
            {
                type: UserType.Account,
                isSelect: filterCondition.filter((item) => item.type === UserType.Account)[0].isSelect,
                onClick: this.onToggleFilterItem.bind(this, UserType.Account),
            },
            {
                type: UserType.SNS,
                isSelect: filterCondition.filter((item) => item.type === UserType.SNS)[0].isSelect,
                onClick: this.onToggleFilterItem.bind(this, UserType.SNS),
            },
        ];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `enum` has only numeric values:

```
export enum UserType {
    Guest = 1,
    SNS = 2,
    Account = 3,
    Certified = 4,
}

const UserTypeEntries = Object.entries(UserType)
    .filter((e): e is [keyof typeof UserType, number] => typeof e[1] === 'number');

// or values only
const UserTypeValues = Object.values(UserType)
    .filter((e): e is UserType => typeof e === 'number');
```

Then just map the values on attribute options:

```
const atrributeOptions = UserTypeValues.map(userType => ({
    type: userType,
    isSelect: filterCondition.filter((item) => item.type === userType)[0].isSelect,
    onClick: this.onToggleFilterItem.bind(this, userType),
}));
```